# Excel Array formula for sum if combination

Tags: excel-2007, excel-2010

Can some one help me out with the formula

```
=SUM(((((IF(('RAW Data'!B3:B501="Riz Wan")*('RAW Data'!A3:A501="Active Client"),'RAW Data'!C3:C501))+(IF(('RAW Data'!B3:B501="Riz Wan")*('RAW Data'!A3:A501="Don"),'RAW Data'!C3:C501))+(IF(('RAW Data'!B3:B501="Riz Wan")*('RAW Data'!A3:A501="WSUZ"),'RAW Data'!C3:C501))+(IF(('RAW Data'!B3:B501="Riz Wan")*('RAW Data'!A3:A501="MYS"),'RAW Data'!C3:C501))))))
```

When I entered this formula this works good some times and this doesn't work sometimes I request someone to help me out on this, it's very critical for me pull the reports it is not calculating as expected.

Comment: Also please suggest me any alternate formula for this.

Comment: in this formula i am check for multiple values

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting a formula error for certain inputs?

If so, I would suggest breaking the formula into smaller and smaller constituent parts until you are able to successfully isolate the portion causing the error.

Comment: when enter the formula and in the cell and when i press F2+Shift+enter it is giving as tag kind of thing for me okay, when i click on ignore the error it is not giving the out put

Comment: there is one more thing i need to tell, it is calculating values only for Don and MYS sometimes it calcultes for all sometimes it is not calculation at all.

Comment: any suggestion on how to write formula using sumif function

Comment: Can you post the excel file in question somewhere so that it can be inspected?  It is difficult to make a diagnosis based only on the formula without seeing the actual data on which it is operating.